# Still struggling to install the PHP client for Griddb

Tags: nosql, griddb

Previously, I had an issue attempting to build the PHP client for griddb, due to missing files and headers. I have now resolved that issue, by updating the paths, and pointing to the correct path for the missing files. I am using Version 8.1 of PHP as suggested in the README. However, I am now getting PHP errors when trying to compile the build client. No missing files, but rather, PHP errors. I believe this can happen with an incorrect version of PHP, but I have followed all the guidelines. Please see the screenshot attached. My LD_LIBRARY path and LIBRARY path are set to the correct location of the client.  [image: PHP Version 8.1 errors]